# Building Python 2.7 and Pandas in a different directory

Tags: centos, python, yum

What's the best way to install Python 2.7 and Pandas (with its dependencies), to a separate directory so that it doesn't interact with the OS version? I'm building everything on a separate machine, then moving it over due to restrictions on the box I need it on.

I understand I can't use yum to install packages wherever I want with the *--installroot=* method, and I'm having a rough time pushing everything into one spot with *--prefix=* parameter on configure files.

Comment: What issue do you get with `--prefix=` option? That should do exactly what you want.

Comment: For the dependencies, they appear to not use this parameter and return an error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Anaconda?
https://www.continuum.io/downloads

There is also the lesser version Miniconda, with less packages.

Comment: I didn't realize there was a version of Anaconda that is like this, thanks!